# Sending Emails to Sharepoint 2010 from External Source without Exchange

Tags: email, sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2010, smtp

Wow,

What a topic.

Ok, we have a sharepoint server, (with SMTP services enabled) which can currently accept emails from an email client on the local network with the server address as the smtp outbound server setting.

How do I now enable externally originating emails to hit the same drop folder without exchange? My instinct is to open port 25 on the public gateway and add an MX record on the DNS  hosting configuration.

Here are the steps from the Exchange setup I don't want to do: http://www.managedcompany.com/FAQRetrieve.aspx?ID=35747

Thoughts?

Comment: This may be more complicated.  I see that the client which is currently working is not really sending an email, and the Drop folder is not really receiving an email. The client is simply asking the SMTP server to send the email (which it doesn't actually do).